# JavaScript - For loop with switch statement continually looping

Tags: javascript, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm relatively new to coding and working on a text based RPG game in JavaScript. The following code allows me to progress through the different scenarios where you are approached with a different bad guy.

I used a For loop in conjunction with a Switch statement and had it working prior, but then I re factored my code to make it more OO & prototypal. Now my For loop continues looping and does not exit. I checked the value of [i] throughout and see it properly goes 0-4, but then it restarts at 0 and I can't figure out why?

```
var scenario = new Array();

 //simple function to create the number of scenarios
 function Scenario () {
    howManyScenarios = function(number) {
       for (i=0; i <= number; i++) {
       scenario[i] = ("Scenario " + (1 + i));
    };
};

howManyScenarios(4); //if you change the argument, add additional switch cases

//iterating through my howManyScenarios function to build out scenarios using a switch case
createScenarios = function () {
    var ii = scenario.length;

    for (i=0; i < ii; i++) {

    switch(scenario[i]) {
        case 'Scenario 1':
            alert("You run into a troll");
            b = 0;
            break;
        case 'Scenario 2':
            alert("You find a store to purchase goods from");
            ItemShop();
            break;
        case 'Scenario 3': 
            alert("You run into a ogre");
            b = 1;
            break;
        case 'Scenario 4':
            alert("You run into a warewolf");
            b = 2;
            break;
        case 'Scenario 5':
            alert("You run into a wizard");
            b = 3;
            return;
            break;  
        }; //close out switch cases
    }; //close out my for loop
}; //close out createScenarios function 
createScenarios();
}; //close out Scenario function

Scenario();
```

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/R552r/

Comment: I can't see how these bits of code fit together. I will say that you're using a global instance of the variable `i` and that might be causing you trouble. Try declaring `i` within each function with `var i;` and see if that helps.

Comment: "howManyScenarios" creates an array [Scenario 1, Scenario 2, etc] which I then iterate through in "createScenarios". The reason I'm doing it that way is because I don't know how many scenarios I might decide to use, so I don't want to build them all out separately. 

Tried to declare each var i and that didn't work. It does properly iterate through each scenario, but then i resets to 0 for some reason and it starts over at Troll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop will obviously still continue because you just only ended a case of every loop of `i` and will still test each value in the array of `scenario[i]`.

How about using variable `b` as a handler that if an event like `you run into a troll` has been executed, then set `b` to a number greater than 0 then check if a value has been inserted into `b` before switching into the array again using `if (b) break;` where if `b` has a value greater than 0 then it will be set as `true`.

```
var scenario = new Array();
var b;
//simple function to create the number of scenarios
function Scenario() {
    howManyScenarios = function (number) {
        for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            scenario[i] = ("Scenario " + (1 + i));
        };
    };

    howManyScenarios(4); //if you change the argument, add additional switch cases
    console.log(scenario[i]);
    //iterating through my howManyScenarios function to build out scenarios using a switch case
    createScenarios = function () {
        var ii = scenario.length;

        for (i = 0; i < ii; i++) {
            if (b) break;
            switch (scenario[i]) {
                case 'Scenario 1':
                    alert("You run into a troll");
                    b = 1;
                    break;
                case 'Scenario 2':
                    alert("You find a store to purchase goods from");
                    b = 2;
                    ItemShop();
                    break;
                case 'Scenario 3':
                    alert("You run into a ogre");
                    b = 3;
                    break;
                case 'Scenario 4':
                    alert("You run into a warewolf");
                    b = 4;
                    break;
                case 'Scenario 5':
                    alert("You run into a wizard");
                    b = 5;
                    return;
                    break;
            }; //close out switch cases
        }; //close out my for loop
    }; //close out createScenarios function 
    createScenarios();
}; //close out Scenario function

Scenario();

function ItemShop() {}
```

**ANSWER 2**
This one is one way on how we game developers make a functional game by using a series of object arrays, object classes and the like.

I remade your code into something easier to read, hope you learn something from this. :)

```
var numberofscenarios = 5;
var scenario = []; //array where scenarios will be
//this will be the accessible properties of scenario[] array
var _scenario = function(){
    this.name = ""; //name of scenario
    this.message =  "";
    this.doSomething = 0;
    this.status = 0 ;//1 = finished and 0 = false
};
var _event = function(mobname){
    this.mobname = mobname;
    this.battle = function(){//doSomething
                            console.log("Battle VS "+ this.mobname +" Start!");
                            };
    this.itemShop =  function(){//doSomething
        console.log(this.mobname + ": Welcome to the shop! How may I help you?");
                };
};

//generate the scenarios in the scenario[] array
function generateScenarios() {
    for (i = 0; i <= numberofscenarios; i++) {
            scenario[i] = new _scenario();
            scenario[i].name = i;

        switch (scenario[i].name) {
            case 1:
                scenario[i].message = "You run into a Troll";
                scenario[i].doSomething = new _event("Troll");      
                break;
            case 2:
                scenario[i].message = "You find a store to purchase goods from";
                scenario[i].doSomething = new _event("Shop Keeper");
            break;
            case 3:
                scenario[i].message = "You run into a Ogre";
                scenario[i].doSomething = new _event("Ogre");
                break;
            case 4:
                scenario[i].message = "You run into a Werewolf";
                scenario[i].doSomething = new _event("Werewolf");
                break;              
            case 5:
                scenario[i].message = "You run into a Wizard";
                scenario[i].doSomething = new _event("Wizard");
                break;
        }
    }
}
generateScenarios(); //generate the scenarios

//test the array of scenario class

//test the battle with Troll
console.log(scenario[1].message);
scenario[1].doSomething.battle();

//test the shop
console.log(scenario[2].message);
scenario[2].doSomething.itemShop();

//attempt to fight the Shopkeeper
console.log(scenario[2].message);
scenario[2].doSomething.battle();
```

Comment: I think I'm following your suggestion, but feel like that would be a band-aid fix because my For loop still wouldn't be working properly?

It should iterate through scenario[0]...scenario[4] which then gives me an array to use to proceed through each Switch case. It does properly work in that it goes through each scenario, but then it resets and starts over at the beginning rather than ending. That's where I'm stuck and unless I'm misunderstanding your solution, it wouldn't really address that?

Comment: Being that I'm still new, I'll have to take some time later to read through and understand, but at least at first glance that looks awesome. I appreciate it and I'm sure will learn something from it!

Comment: By the way, tried to vote you up but I don't have the reputation needed yet :)